# Ninject 3.0.0 and Nservicebus 3.0.3 -> Help on Configuration?

Tags: ninject, nservicebus

Does anyone have any thoughts as to how to get the two to come together so I can get injection of the IBus on the class file?

I tried downloading the Official Nservicebus.Ninject package but it appears to be constrained to the 2.x line of Ninject via Nuget.  I went ahead and downloaded the source to the object builder for Ninject.  There's a few issues I'm getting through several trial and error scenarios.

The first was that the IBus is not getting set via property injection.  This could be my misunderstanding of how the Objectbuilder is being utilized, but I was under the impression that by setting the public IBus Bus {get; set;} on a class within the assembly that it would be set for me.

I then went down the route of trying something along the lines of:

```
Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IBus>()
```

That yielded the following:

```
Error activating IBus
More than one matching bindings are available.
Activation path:
1) Request for IBus

Suggestions:
1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IBus only once.
```

If I do an explicit request for the UnicastBus instead of IBus I do get one instance, but it will bomb out on the base.Activite with the following:

```
More than one matching bindings are available.
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IBus into property Bus of type TimeoutMessageConverter
  1) Request for TimeoutMessageConverter

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IBus only once.
```

I do not claim to be a ninject master (background is spring.net) as this project was handed to me to see if I could leverage it's existing infrastructure that uses Ninject and get a reference to the Bus to invoke a publish from a dispatcher in the project.  Been spinning my wheels on this for the better part of day.

Here's the NServiceBus Module being loaded by Ninject (set up taken from another SO post):

```
public class NServiceBusModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
       this.Bind<IBus>().ToConstant(this.CreateBus()).InSingletonScope();
    }

    private IBus CreateBus()
    {
        return Configure.With()
                .DefineEndpointName("publishMe")
                .NinjectBuilder(this.Kernel)
                .XmlSerializer()
                .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(true)
                .InMemorySubscriptionStorage()
                .UnicastBus()                    
                .CreateBus().Start(() =>
                Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
    }


}
```

I'm not leveraging any IWantCustomInitialization in the EndpointConfig as I thought this was all I would need to get a reference to the Bus.

I have another idea I can approach where I continue to separate the project out a bit that I believe would work just fine (have the web app --setting up bus in the global.ascx -- directly publish to an endpoint and go from there), but trying to stay within the initial requirements of the project outline.

I can supply more information if need be.

Comment: I'm the original author of the nservicebus ninject integration. I haven't had time to upgrade it to NServiceBus 3.0. There is also a new unit of work scope introduced in NServiceBus 3.0 which is currently not supported by the current ninject integration implementation. Remo Gloor and I well be at Skills Matter in London next week meeting Udi Dahan and we will try to update the integration together with Udi Dahans Guidelines (if necessary). 

Meanwhile you should define a binding for IBus. That should be taken care of automatically by the infrastructure.

Comment: So any news? I'm on the point of abandoning Ninject, unfortunately. Seems a pity that it requires the experts in both projects just to write a DI integration. Far too complex for me!

Comment: yeah i should commented much earlier on this.  Somewhere along the way, the other developer switched to autofac.  Nothing against Ninject itself, just some design decision.  I've seen some other posts in the forums for Nservicebus, the most recent I believe that Andreas stated the teams had met, but nothing on time frame.  I have yet to try out Daniel's and Tim's responses as I've been researching other areas of this new project.

Comment: has anyone been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`NinjectBuilder` adds the `IBus` binding. You have two options:

1. Use Rebind in your code
2. Just call `CreateBus()` without adding the binding